# I am trying to recreate this view in power apps in a screen

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-canvas

[image]

I have a list in SharePoint that stores the user as a text field. The task is a drop down selection of projects A, B, C, etc., they will also need to have start and end dates for each project. and I want them to be able to input hours for each project at once for a two-week period. then there will be a button to patch it to another sharepoint list. Any advice would be great!